# Is there a FireFox extension which blocks new (blank) tabs when opening a file from link?

Tags: web-browser

This functionality used to be in the old Tab Mix Plus:

Click on a URL that is a PDF on the web.  The download occurs and a file was opened inside my PDF default reader (Acrobat reader).  As that occurs, a new tab, blank, was NOT opened in the browser.  And the browser remained on the tab which had the URL.

Now, with past changes to FireFox, the tabmix plus doesn't seem to exist.  So, when I clickon the URL, a new tab is opened -- with no content.

Is there a method, now, to getting "suppress blank tab on opening files"?

I distinguish this from the general methods for forcing a URL to open (or not open) in a new tab.

The old tab mix plus had, I think a space to declare the file types where the new tab was not opened.

Thanks !